# How to wrap text from 2 different textblocks with different alignments

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to wrap text from 2 different `textblocks`.
The reason I need 2 is because they both have a different text format/alignment.

It currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like the `xx.xx` to be in the red circle if there is still room (like in the image).

This is the xaml:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBlock
        Text="texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext"
        TextAlignment="Left"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        FontSize="10"
        Foreground="LightGray"
        Text="xx.xx"
        TextAlignment="Right"/>
</TextBlock>
```

`Inlines` do not work either as `Run`'s do not support alignment (and I need 2 different alignments).

Essentially [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/) is a perfect example of the behavior I want:

[image]

I've tried a lot of variations of my current code but either the `xx.xx` starts on a newline or the other text will overlap.

Comment: You can combine your text into `Inlines` block under one textblock

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks! I will jump right into it to see if that works for what I need. If it doesn't I'll change the question accordingly

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `run`'s do not support alignment, I need to align the text left and the xx.xx right. Ill change the question so it reflects this. Thanks for your help either way

Comment: I'll add a short snippet as an answer

Comment: Did you solve your problem?:) Is there any information needed here?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Some things took priority. I'm implementing a solution and will post that here for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it using the following way (I've restricted the `TexBlock` size to wrap the text)

```
<TextBlock Width="200" TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text="texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext"/>
    <Run FontSize="10" Text="xx.xx" Foreground="LightGray"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Actually it looks like as (`xx.xx` text is displayed on the same line)

[image]

Comment: Nice solution but I need the text aligned left and the xx.xx aligned right. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Parent `TextBlock` alignment is set to right `TextAlignment="Right"`, the text inside is aligned according it

Comment: Yes but that is precisely the problem, I need 2 different alignments to wrap. If this isn't possible at all I'd take that as an answer too. the xx.xx always has to be on the right and the other text has to align left like "normal" text. And sadly `Run` does not support alignment :'(

Comment: Ohh, I see. Well, if width of this text is fixed, you can manually align `xx.xx` text using spaces, because spaces inside `<Run/>` blocks are significant

Comment: Sadly it is a binding in production, this text is just an example. Thanks for the effort

Comment: As a dirty workaround, you can create a converter which adds space before `xx.xx` text based on `TextBlock` or its width

Comment: Thats a good idea! I will try to implement that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To make it look like in your example from Whatsapp, you can put both TextBlocks into a `Grid` and position them accordingly.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock
        Text="xx.xx"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        FontSize="10"
        Foreground="LightGray" />
    <TextBlock
        Text="texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext this is text texttexttext dfgdffdg fgffgf"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

This is as simple as it can get to achieve what you are trying to achieve and it allows you to add any other controls to the `xx.xx` part, like in the Whatsapp example (the Check icon). The only problem with this solution is the situation from the top text from your Whatsapp example, because the text will simply be on top of the `xx.xx` text.

If I really wanted to achieve something like this, then I would programmatically check (every time the `Text` changes) the width of the `TextBlock` and whether or not it overlaps with the `xx.xx` `TextBlock`. And if it does, I would split it into two `TextBlock` objects: One for the text above, and one just for the last line. It's complicated, but I don't know of any other option how to achieve something like this. It's a lot of work for a little UI tweak. :)